# Проблема регистрации

Tags: php

Пишет вот это

> `Вы ошиблись при наборе URL в браузере. Вероятнее всего, сервер пытается найти файл Z:/home/php/www/function.mysql-connect, которого не существует.`
>
> `В случае использования CGI-скриптов, корректные пути к CGI-директориям следующие: не могу понять.`

Comment: А в чем, собственно, заключается вопрос?

И поясните о какой регистрации идет речь, кто пишет и что вообще происходит. Точнее — что Вы делаете, что Вы хотите получить, и что идет не так (последнее, вроде бы, описано, не хватает первых двух).

Comment: Это как?
 
"В случае использования CGI-скриптов, корректные пути к CGI-директориям следующие: не могу понять."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

если тестишь на компе с помощью денвера то создай папку `имя.хост` в папку `/WebServers/home/` и внутри папку `www` и туда свой сайт загрузи, и сделай рестарт денвера, потом введи в браузере то что ты написал `сервер.хост`